# ReactJS - Child components DO NOT render when imported component used, but DO when explicitly marked up in parent element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a voting app for a freeCodeCamp.org project.

Every poll has a list of voting options.

Within a single poll, I am trying to render all available options to vote on.

Marking up the voting option directly in the poll component works, but does not work when I factor out the markup to a "option" child component.

In the react dev-tools, a connect tag appears but no DIV, leading me to think that I'm handling the rendering of it all wrong.

**IMAGE**
[Child component does not render (via React Dev Tools)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdPV5.jpg)

**a_poll.js ( THE PARENT COMPONENT )**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PollOption from './poll_option';
import  * as Actions from '../actions';

class APoll extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchAPoll(this.props.params.postId);
}  

renderOption(pollData) {
    //console.log("renderOption:", pollData.options);
    return (
           pollData.options.forEach(function(option) {
              return (
                <PollOption title={option.title} value={option.value} />
              ); 
           })
        );
}

render() {
    const a_poll = this.props.a_poll ? this.props.a_poll : "nothing here";
    return (
        <div>
            <div>{ a_poll.title } : {a_poll.user_name}</div>
            <div>{a_poll.map(this.renderOption)}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

};

function mapStateToProps({a_poll}) {
return { 
    a_poll
};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, Actions)(aPoll);
```

**PollOption.js ( THE CHILD COMPONENT )**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import  * as Actions from '../actions';

function PollOption(props) {

return (
    <div key={ this.props.title }  style={{ clear: 'left' }}>
            <h6>{ this.props.title }hgjgjg : </h6>
            <div style={{marginTop : "5px"}}>
                <div style={{ 
                        display: "inline-black",
                        float: "left",
                        backgroundColor : "cornflowerblue",
                        height : "50",
                        padding : "15",
                        marginBottom : "15px",
                        minWidth: "50px",
                        width : option.value,
                        color: "white",
                        lineHeight: "25px"
                    }}>
                    <div style={{ 
                        display : "inline-block",
                    }}>
                        { this.props.value }
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <button 
                    style={{ 
                    display: "inline-block",
                    height: "50",
                    marginLeft: "20",
                    }} 
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                    onClick={console.log("vote buttoned clicked")}
                    > 
                    Vote 
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
);
} 

export default connect(Actions)(PollOption);
```

Comment: In your functional component (PollOption.js) you need to refer to the `props` argument not `this.props`. `this.props` should be `undefined` in your functional component.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm afraid it didn't fix the issue. I then tried to convert it to a class and use "this" as I had been trying to do, and the results were the same. >_<; Any more ideas?

Comment: It also seems like you don't need to use `connect` with `PollOption`. Why are you using `connect` here?

Comment: I will have a vote button call an action, in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to just mark this up with simple syntax and skip most of your code. The problem is the fact you're not actually updating things so when the state changes there's nothing to update.

Here's a simple component you can test that might explain your problem:

//Test.js

```
import React from 'react'

let counter = 0
class TestPage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [
        'a','b','c'
      ]
    })
  }

  badAddToState() {
    this.state.data.push(('bad' + counter++))
  }

  addToState() {
    let copy = this.state.data.slice() //make a new array
    copy.push('good' + counter++)
    let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
      data: copy
    })
    this.setState(newState)
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state || { data: [] } //ES6 destructuring syntax
     return (
       <div>
         <button
           onClick = { (e) => { 
             this.badAddToState()
             console.log('bad clicked')
             console.log('counter->' + counter)
           } }
         >
           BAD
         </button>
         <button
         onClick = { (e) => { 
             this.addToState()
             console.log('good clicked')
             console.log('counter->' + counter)
           } }
         >
           GOOD
         </button>
         <h1>Good data</h1>
         { this.state.data.map( (x) => {
           return (<div key={x}>Hi I'm {x}</div>) //this is effectively your child
         })}
       </div>

     )
  }
}
export default TestPage
```

So what's going on? Basically the "BAD" button is updating your state but not telling the component it has modified the state. The "GOOD" button uses the `setState` method to push data back to the component saying "hey I need an update"(which you can see actually produces a result, but the component isn't updating.)

[image]

So why did I give you this example to play with? I think you're not seeing how Redux work at a base level. Redux (connect) is taking a global state and mapping that to the `{component}.props` In your case you're just mapping the actions to the properties (something you don't need to do, but can do).

When you fetch items from your mounting (much like I just pushed an array) you need to DO SOMETHING with it. In typical a Redux pattern that would mean you refect the global state.

***Because your component doesn't appear to depend on your result there's no reason to redraw it right?***

You want to make sure that the "poll" you're fetching is mapped. And does it make sense to have the child instantiate an action to retrieve something if the parent already knows about it?

Simplify this:

```
//...boilerplate child | It isn't connected to redux
render() {
  return(
    <Markup>
      { this.props.poll.name }
      <button 
        onClick={e=>{
          //This changes the global state **1**
          dispatch(doSomethingEvent()) //confession I use Thunk because I like more actions
        }}>
          Do Something
        </button>
    </Markup>
  )
}

//...boilerplate paernt
render() {
  //**2** WHICH IS RENDERED HERE WHEN IT CHANGES
  const { dispatch, polls } = this.props
  return (
    <div>
      { polls.map( (poll, index)=>{
        return <Poll pollObject={poll} key={index || poll.uuid } dispatch={dispatch} />
      } ) }
    </div>
  )
}     

///...mapping
connect(state => {
  polls = state.whereEverYouStorePolls
})(Parent)
```

1) The action changes the state--you didn't post your code but it is the "business logic"
2) The change is reflected in the parent which propagates to the child.

Does that help?

The short answer is that you're displaying your component but never calling render because you're expecting the poll to reflect the state of the fetch action without depending on it. Flip the data-structure--the render shouldn't ask for data, it should be provided data.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I'm studying your suggestion but I feel like my inclusion of connect has distracted your focus. The poll option renders correctly if I write it directly into the a_poll renderoption() function. To clean up a_poll I merely want to pass the title and number of votes (option.value) down as props and render them in the child (PollOption). I believe all of the data is reaching the parent (a_poll) properly. Please don't worry about the vote button's use of actions or thunks at this time. Thanks again. I'll continue to study your answer.

Comment: @Zach are you saying if you replace `data.map(poll => { this.functionCall })` with `data.map(poll => { return (<div>{poll}</div>) }` it renders? That doesn't really make sense but stranger things have happened.

Comment: Yes, if I write    a_poll.map(this.renderOption) and for renderOption do renderOption(option) { return <div>{option.title}<div> } , it renders correctly. But if I instead do <PollOption title={option.title} etc. > as in the original question above, it doesn't work.

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return a value--switch it to `map`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: I usually have it as map but when I created this questions I forgot to change it back. So, that wasn't the issue. In my child component (PollOption), my placeholder console.log in the onClick was causing a problem. after setting it up so that is calls a proper click handler, it worked fine..many hours later....;_;

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was that in my child component (PollOption) my placeholder onClick={console.log...} function was causing the whole child component to fail to render. Once I set it up to the point just before calling an actual action, it bubbled up through it's parent component just fine.

The result is I feel like I have a tidier component. Was it worth it? Maybe.

Thank you @Daniel B. Chapman for your help and @Tom Coughlin for your help.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import  * as Actions from '../actions';

class PollOption extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

handleVoteClick(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("handleclick was clicked");
}

render(props){
    return (
        <div key={this.props.title}  style={{ clear: 'left' }}>
            <h6>{this.props.title} : </h6>
            <div style={{marginTop : "5px"}}>
                <div style={{ 
                        display: "inline-black",
                        float: "left",
                        backgroundColor : "cornflowerblue",
                        height : "50",
                        padding : "15",
                        marginBottom : "15px",
                        minWidth: "50px",
                        width : this.props.value,
                        color: "white",
                        lineHeight: "25px"
                    }}>
                    <div style={{ 
                        display : "inline-block",
                    }}>
                        {this.props.value}
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <button 
                    style={{ 
                    display: "inline-block",
                    height: "50",
                    marginLeft: "20",
                    }} 
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                    onClick={this.handleVoteClick} <------this guy!---
                    > 
                    Vote 
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
};

export default PollOption;
```